# My Enemy Slime Object always chasing me even if statement says otherwise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I want my enemy only chasing me when its player and enemy in the same static (immovable) chamber but either way its always chasing player. Code, inspector and scene attachments below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c0uS.jpg)

here behind slime chamber but my enemy still chasing player.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGb8r.png)

This is enemy inspector even it shows enemy not in the chamber.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySlimeController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SlimeScriptableObject Slime;
    public GameObject target;
    public GameObject chamber;
    public GameObject player;
    public float followDistance;
    [SerializeField]
    public bool _playerInSight;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _targetInSight;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _inChamber = true;
    private Rigidbody _rb;
    private Vector3 _difference;
    private Vector3 _direction;
    private Vector3 _velocity;
    void Start()
    {
        _rb = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        InvokeRepeating("ControlMovement", 1, Slime.invokeTime);
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            _playerInSight = true;
        }
        else if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            _targetInSight = true;
            target = other.gameObject;
        }
        else if ((other.CompareTag("EnemyChamber")))
        {
            _inChamber = true;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            _playerInSight = false;
        }
        else if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            _targetInSight = false;
        }
        else if ((other.CompareTag("EnemyChamber"))){
            _inChamber = false;
        }

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        MoveBackward(_rb, chamber, Slime.speed);
    }

    public void ControlMovement()
    {
        if (_inChamber == true)
        {
            if (_playerInSight && _targetInSight) MoveTowardsEntity(_rb, target, Slime.speed);

            if (_playerInSight && !_targetInSight) MoveTowardsPlayer(_rb, player, Slime.speed);

            if (!_playerInSight && _targetInSight) MoveTowardsPlayer(_rb, player, Slime.speed);

            if (!_playerInSight && !_targetInSight) MoveTowardsPlayer(_rb, player, Slime.speed);
        }
        if (_inChamber == false)
        {
            MoveBackward(_rb,chamber, Slime.speed);
        }
    }

    protected void MoveTowardsEntity(Rigidbody entity, GameObject target, float speed)
    {
        Debug.Log("�nside Target mov");
        _difference = target.transform.position - entity.transform.position;
        if ((_difference.x <= followDistance && _difference.x >= -followDistance) && (_difference.z <= followDistance && _difference.z >= -followDistance)) return;
        _direction = _difference.normalized;
        _velocity = _direction * speed;
        entity.velocity = _velocity;
    }
    protected void MoveBackward(Rigidbody entity, GameObject target, float speed)
    {
        Debug.Log("�nside Backward mov");
        _difference = target.transform.position - entity.transform.position;
        if ((_difference.x <= followDistance && _difference.x >= -followDistance) && (_difference.z <= followDistance && _difference.z >= -followDistance)) return;
        _direction = _difference.normalized;
        _velocity = _direction * speed;
        entity.velocity = _velocity;
    }
    protected void MoveTowardsPlayer(Rigidbody entity, GameObject target, float speed)
    {
        Debug.Log("�nside Player mov");
        _difference = target.transform.position - entity.transform.position;
        if ((_difference.x <= followDistance && _difference.x >= -followDistance) && (_difference.z <= followDistance && _difference.z >= -followDistance)) return;
        _direction = _difference.normalized;
        _velocity = _direction * speed;
        entity.velocity = _velocity;
    }
}
```

i tried checking if statement but everything seems to me normal. But i dont understand my enemy chasing. I copy pasted my slime controller script and edited it. Here my slime controller script:

````
 public SlimeScriptableObject Slime;
    public GameObject target;
    public GameObject player;
    public float followDistance;
    [SerializeField]
    public bool _playerInSight;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _targetInSight;
    private bool _isTouched = false;
    private Rigidbody _rb;
    private Vector3 _difference;
    private Vector3 _direction;
    private Vector3 _velocity;
    void Start()
    {
        _rb = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        target = player;
        InvokeRepeating("ControlMovement", 1, Slime.invokeTime);
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            _playerInSight = true;
        }
        else if(other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            _targetInSight = true;
            target = other.gameObject;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            _playerInSight = false;
        }
        else if(other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            _targetInSight = false;
        }

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        _isTouched = true;
        MoveBackward(_rb, player , Slime.speed);
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        _isTouched = false;
    }

    public void ControlMovement()
    {
        if (_isTouched == false)
        {
            if (_playerInSight && _targetInSight) MoveTowardsEntity(_rb, target, Slime.speed);

            if (_playerInSight && !_targetInSight) MoveTowardsPlayer(_rb, player, Slime.speed);

            if (!_playerInSight && _targetInSight) MoveTowardsPlayer(_rb, player, Slime.speed);

            if (!_playerInSight && !_targetInSight) MoveTowardsPlayer(_rb, player, Slime.speed);
        }
        else
        {
            MoveBackward(_rb, player, Slime.speed);
        }
    }

    protected void MoveTowardsEntity(Rigidbody entity, GameObject target, float speed)
    {
        Debug.Log("Green İnside Target mov");
        _difference = target.transform.position - entity.transform.position;
        if ((_difference.x <= followDistance && _difference.x >= -followDistance) && (_difference.z <= followDistance && _difference.z >= -followDistance)) return;
        _direction = _difference.normalized;
        _velocity = _direction * speed;
        entity.velocity = _velocity;
    }
    protected void MoveBackward(Rigidbody entity, GameObject target, float speed)
    {
        Debug.Log("Green İnside Backward mov");
        _difference = target.transform.position - entity.transform.position;
        if ((_difference.x <= followDistance && _difference.x >= -followDistance) && (_difference.z <= followDistance && _difference.z >= -followDistance)) return;
        _direction = _difference.normalized;
        _velocity = _direction * speed;
        entity.velocity = _velocity;
    }
    protected void MoveTowardsPlayer(Rigidbody entity, GameObject target, float speed)
    {
        Debug.Log("Green İnside Player mov");
        _difference = target.transform.position - entity.transform.position;
        if ((_difference.x <= followDistance && _difference.x >= -followDistance) && (_difference.z <= followDistance && _difference.z >= -followDistance)) return;
        _direction = _difference.normalized;
        _velocity = _direction * speed;
        entity.velocity= _velocity;
    }```
````